# How can I check for errors without saving the file?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, text-editor, code-editor

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the [PHP Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) extension.

When I save a PHP file, it checks for errors and successfully finds any syntax errors in the file.

But sometimes I don't want to save the file yet; I just want to check for errors. How can I do this? I don't see a button for it, and they don't appear automatically in the Problems area.

[image]

Comment: Hi, the error is the compile/build error or the intellisense error? Could you please share the example code and I will try to test it in my side.

Answer (score 0):

You can install PHP IntelliSense Extension https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php .